# Datepicker not returning it's value

Tags: datepicker, php

I'm going nuts trying to figure out why the datepicker variable is not being sent via email with the rest of my form submission?

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/andy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/mq.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


<!-- Google Web Fonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maiden+Orange' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



  <style>
  .cap-overlay .button { margin-top:10px}
  .cap-overlay{width: 100%; color:#fff; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);left:0;padding:12px; line-height: 1.4em;font-size:14px}
  .cap-overlay h5 {color:#fff;}
  a[data-toggle="drop-panel"] {display: block;}
  </style>

  <script>

  $(window).load(function(){
  $('.hcaption').hcaptions();
});



</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".overlay").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                opacity: 0.8,
                css : {
                    'background-color' : '#000'
                }
            }
        },

        maxWidth  : 900,
        maxHeight : 380,
        fitToView : false,
        width   : 650,
        height    : 400,
        autoSize  : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
      helpers   : { 
   overlay : {closeClick: false} // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
  }
      });
</script>

<script>
var hdate = $('input#hdate').datepicker('getDate');
</script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

   <form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
    <label class='form_error_title'>Please check the required fields</label>
</div>



<ol class='phpfmg_form' >

<li class='field_block' id='field_0_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Date of Hunt</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>

<input type="text" name="hdate" id="hdate" class="datepicker input-large">


  <div id='field_0_tip' class='instruction'></div>
  </div>
</li>

<br>

<li class='field_block' id='field_1_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Name</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <input type="text" name="name"  id="name" value="" class='text_box input-large'>
  <div id='field_1_tip' class='instruction'></div>
  </div>
</li>

<br>

<li class='field_block' id='field_2_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>E-Mail Address</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <input type="text" name="email"  id="email" value="" class='text_box input-large'>
  <div id='field_2_tip' class='instruction'></div>
  </div>
</li>

<br>

<li class='field_block' id='field_3_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Phone Number</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <input type="text" name="phone"  id="phone" value="" class='text_box input-large'>
  <div id='field_3_tip' class='instruction'></div>
  </div>
</li>

<br>

<li class='field_block' id='field_4_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Select the hunt you're interested in:</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='hunt_type' id='gator'  value="Gator"   class='form_checkbox'  ><label class='form_choice_text' for='field_4_0'>Gator</label><br>  
<input type='checkbox' name='hunt_type' id='hog'  value="Hog"   class='form_checkbox'  ><label class='form_choice_text' for='field_4_1'>Hog</label><br>  
<input type='checkbox' name='hunt_type' id='dove'  value="Dove"   class='form_checkbox'  ><label class='form_choice_text' for='field_4_2'>Dove</label><br>  
  </div>
</li>

<br>

<li class='field_block' id='field_5_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Total # of Guests</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <select name='guests' id='total-guests' class='text_select'    >  
<option value="1" >1</option> 
<option value="2" >2</option> 
<option value="3" >3</option> 
<option value="4" >4</option> 
<option value="5" >5</option> 
<option value="6" >6</option> 
</select>
  <div id='field_5_tip' class='instruction'></div>
  </div>
</li>

<br>

<li class='field_block' id='field_6_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Additional Information?</label> <label class='form_required' >&nbsp;</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <textarea name="info" id="info" rows=4 cols=25 class='text_area  input-large'></textarea>

  <div id='field_6_tip' class='instruction'></div>
  </div>
</li>


<!-- Add Captcha Here -->


            <li>
            <div class='col_label'>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class='form_submit_block col_field'>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class='form_button'>  

                <span id='phpfmg_processing' style='display:none;'>
                    <img id='phpfmg_processing_gif' src='admin.php?mod=image&amp;func=processing' border=0 alt='Processing...'> <label id='phpfmg_processing_dots'></label>
                </span>
            </div>
            </li>

</ol>




</form>

        </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/collapse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tab.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // assuming the controls you want to attach the plugin to 
    // have the "datepicker" class set
    $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();

 });

  </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my php:

```
<?php

$hdate = $_POST['hdate'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$hunt_type = $_POST['hunt_type'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

$to = "andyw504@gmail.com";
$subject = "Some subject";
$body = "You have a new reservation!<br><br>
Date of Hunt: $hdate<br>
Name: $name<br>
E-mail: $email<br>
Phone Number: $phone<br>
Type of Hunt: $hunt_type<br>
Number of Guests: $guests<br>
Comments: $info<br>";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $to" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
echo "Email sent.";
exit;
?>
```

They've asked me to add more detail. The datepicker is popping up and putting the date in the text area. When I call that variable to send via email it is blank. Every other field is recorded and sent in the e-mail except the date, which is one of the most important parts of the form.

Comment: First start by removing the dot in the first `$headers .= "Reply-To: info@yoursite.com\r\n";` to read as `$headers = "Reply-To: info@yoursite.com\r\n";`

Comment: and if you have some JS happening for your date picker, it's not happening with what you posted. Post your full HTML with the form inside it.

Comment: plus your headers are wrong

Comment: You also need to remove `$name = "$name";`

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT  (new code for form and PHP)

First download Pickadate.js and look inside the `index.htm` file.

- https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js

You will see this `<input id="input_01" class="datepicker" type="text">` just change that to `<input id="input_01" class="datepicker" type="text" name="hdate">` and you'll be in business.

Plus there are a few themes to choose from.

- Added `[]` in `name='hunt_type[]'` for all three checkboxes. This is important, because if someone chose 2 or more, only one will show up in the form.

Also added this in PHP handler which will handle the array for "**hunt type**":

```
foreach($_POST['hunt_type'] as $value) {
    $hunt_type.= $value . "\n";
}
```

### HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">

Hunt date:
<input type="text" name="hdate">
<br>


Hunt type:
<li class='field_block' id='field_4_div'><div class='col_label'>
  <label class='form_field'>Select the hunt you're interested in:</label> <label class='form_required' >*</label> </div>
  <div class='col_field'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='hunt_type[]' id='gator'  value="Gator"   class='form_checkbox'  ><label class='form_choice_text' for='field_4_0'>Gator</label><br>  
<input type='checkbox' name='hunt_type[]' id='hog'  value="Hog"   class='form_checkbox'  ><label class='form_choice_text' for='field_4_1'>Hog</label><br>  
<input type='checkbox' name='hunt_type[]' id='dove'  value="Dove"   class='form_checkbox'  ><label class='form_choice_text' for='field_4_2'>Dove</label><br>  
  </div>
</li>
<br>

Name:
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>

Email:
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>

Tel:
<input type="text" name="phone">
<br>

Guests:
<input type="text" name="guests">
<br>


Comments:<br>
<textarea rows="6" name="info" cols="38"></textarea>

<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

### PHP handler (handler.php)

```
<?php

$hdate = $_POST['hdate'];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
//$hunt_type = $_POST['hunt_type'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

$to = "email@example.com";
$subject = "Some subject" . "\r\n";

foreach($_POST['hunt_type'] as $value) {
    $hunt_type.= $value . "\n";
}

$body = "You have a new reservation!<br><br>
Date of Hunt: $hdate<br>
Name: $name<br>
E-mail: $email<br>
Phone Number: $phone<br>
Type of Hunt: $hunt_type<br>
Number of Guests: $guests<br>
Comments: $info<br>";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $to" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
echo "Email sent.";
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting no mail sent now. I removed the $name and the .'s after the headers. The page is live at:

www.nolabyg.com/_z/reservation.html

Comment: Using your php I was able to get my e-mails sending again, but still the datepicker field is empty; seems if I could type in the date myself it would read it but because I'm using the picker (it won't let me manually enter text) maybe the info isn't being passed.

Comment: @user2720175 This is a JS-based datepicker, yes? Those can be tricky at times. Can you edit your question and put your full HTML/form and datepicker codes? I can have a look at it, but can't promise anything. I'll do my best.

Comment: @user2720175 Try changing `$hunt_date = $_POST['hunt_date'];` to `$hunt_date = $_POST['hdate'];` because of this in your form `<input type="text" name="hdate" id="hdate" class="datepicker input-large">` doesn't match your handler codes

Comment: Ok yes I have changed the code thinking I had hunt_date somewhere else. They are both now 'hdate' and still the same thing.

Comment: @user2720175 what do you mean by "still the same", what is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: The datepicker is popping up and putting the date in the text area. When I call that variable to send via email it is blank. Every other field is recorded and sent in the e-mail except the date, which is one of the most important parts of the form.

-- This is the Email I receive --

You have a new reservation!

Date of Hunt: 
Name: Andrew Johnson
E-mail: andyw50@gmail.com
Phone Number: 504-456-1234
Type of Hunt: Gator
Number of Guests: 1
Comments: BLah Blah

Comment: @user2720175 Did you change to this `Date of Hunt: $hdate<br>` instead of `Date of Hunt: $hunt_date<br>`?

Comment: It must have something to do with the datepicker appearing to work but the field not knowing it has a date entered into it, even though the date is enetered upon clicking the date on the popup picker.

Comment: Yes. I have updated my original question. Thanks for this btw.

Comment: @user2720175 You're welcome. I'm going to see what I can do on my end, to see what's causing this. I'll keep you posted either way.

Comment: This is in my head tag: 

<script>
    var hdate = $('input#hdate').datepicker('getDate');
    </script>

...and... this is right above my closing </body> tag:

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // assuming the controls you want to attach the plugin to 
    // have the "datepicker" class set
    $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();

 });

  </script>

Not sure if this is conflicting with anything else.

Comment: @user2720175 I tried, the Lord knows I tried. That Zebra picker is not very friendly, however I do have GOOD NEWS for you. I have a date picker here that I tested with, and was successful. If you want to download the ZIP file for it, visit https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js or find another one similar. I was able to get the date from it. If you do get that one, look inside the `index.html` demo file and you will see this `<input id="input_01" class="datepicker" type="text">` just change that to `<input id="input_01" class="datepicker" type="text" name="hdate">` and you'll be in business.

Comment: @user2720175 Plus, I noticed something else that will need to be modified in your form and your handler, is the `hunt type`. If someone chooses all three, only one will show up, so I will modify my code to reflect that.

Comment: @user2720175 I also had one which doesn't require an additional library, however the positioning could be a problem. I made up a Pastebin file for you: **http://pastebin.com/WhJWRX9F**

Comment: Thanks for your help Fred. The Zebra Picker must have been the issue the whole time because once I switched it out everything worked perfectly. Once I figure out how to rep you I will. ;) Cheers.